# numbers at the beginning in ntheorem

Tags: ntheorem

How can I get ntheorem (`\usepackage{ntheorem}`)to write

1.7 Theorem

instead of

Theorem 1.7
?

I thought that was easy enough, but can't find anything with google.

Comment: I don.t know how `ntheorem` does this, but `amsthm` uses `\swapnumbers` before the relevant `\newtheorem` definitions.  `ntheorem` may have something similar.

Comment: @barbarabeeton From the docs of `ntheorem`, section 3.2.2: "Also, `\swapnumbers` is not implemented. Here, the user has to express his definitions by the `\newtheoremstyle`command provided by `ntheorem.sty`, including the use of `\theoremheaderfont`and `\theorembodyfont`."

Comment: @epR8GaYuh: this is valid for the `amsthm` option, which tries to emulate the latter package. When used on its own, ntheorem defines the `change` theorem style, which does the job, as my answer demonstrates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is indeed easy: use the `change` style.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{ntheorem}
\theoremstyle{change}
\theoremseparator{.}
\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}[section]

\begin{document}

\section{Some section}

\begin{thm}
  Sometimes 2 plus 2 do not add up to 4.
\end{thm}

\end{document}
```

[image]